# how to call java from ubuntu inside the docker

Tags: java, ubuntu

I was trying to extract dump.jar file then convert to csv file using this java command in ubuntu-docker (Linux platform) the code has no syntax error but there is no java, so it cannot process. How shall I call java from ubuntu inside the docker?

install Java but there is not enough space

ANY IDEA please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

trying

1. connect container with user root
   `docker exec -it -u root container_name /bin/bash`
2. install java 11 or other version

   `apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk`

   `java --version`

now you can use java in docker container

Comment: HI Kiu Kiu Duck Pea, thanks for help, it works!